How to selected the Grouped items along with Group name in RadzenDropDown?
Currently We are using RadzenDropDown. Where we have scenario where , we need to select the entire group upon clicking on the grouped item.

Is there any property to enable this?
have checked all the property where i can enable this & select all the items under the group but didn't succeeded.

The latest version of Radzen is updated. Currently group by selection ,Filter with group names are also available.
